# mongoDB return only one field from aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I have 2 collections:

Users:

```
"_id": {
    "$oid": "62f7gsda96211065456322a10fe"
},
"name": "test",
"roles": ["user"],
"type": "user",
"fullName": "Test Test",
"email": "test_test@test.com",
"password_scheme": "pbkdf2",
"iterations": 10,
"derived_key": "ef150b4daa328703e68ae57f112321580ce95aa4",
"salt": "1e22243068bbsbsdva8d6459a683e2903",
"isDiactivated": false,
"idclient": {
    "$oid": "60f7cca7321da11252a10fd"
}
```

Timelogs:

```
"_id": {
    "$oid": "60f7ccbd62110611252a130a"
},
"dtstart": {
    "$date": "2020-06-01T15:24:35.388Z"
},
"idstory": {
    "$oid": "60f7ccad62110611252a1271"
},
"idworkday": {
    "$oid": "60f7ccbd62110611252a1308"
},
"dtend": {
    "$date": "2020-06-01T15:35:36.856Z"
},
"idclient": {
    "$oid": "60f7cca7321da11252a10fd"
},
"idowner": {
    "$oid": "62f7gsda96211065456322a10fe"
}
```

in the query I need to get timelogs. Timelogs has an "idowner" field that refers to users. I want to get all the data from timelogs, but also get the "name" of the user from the Users collection.

It should look like this:

```
"_id": {
"$oid": "60f7ccbd62110611252a130a"
},
"dtstart": {
"$date": "2020-06-01T15:24:35.388Z"
},
"idstory": {
"$oid": "60f7ccad62110611252a1271"
},
"idworkday": {
"$oid": "60f7ccbd62110611252a1308"
},
"dtend": {
"$date": "2020-06-01T15:35:36.856Z"
},
"idclient": {
"$oid": "60f7cca762110611252a10fd"
},
"idowner": {
"$oid": "62f7gsda96211065456322a10fe"
},
"name": "test"
```

Comment: Hopefully `password_scheme: "pbkdf2"` does not store the password as clear text. You should **never** do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$lookup` to join 2 collections

```
db.timelogs.aggregate([{ 
    $lookup: { 
                from: "user", //remote collection name
                localField: "idowner.oid", //timelogs collection field
                foreignField: "_id.oid", //remote collection mapping field
                as: "idowner" //to be imported as
              } 
  }
  ,{$unwind:"$idowner"}
,{$project:{ 
            dtstart:1,
            idstory:1,
            idworkday:1,
            dtend:1,
            idclient:1,
            idowner:"$idowner._id",
            name:"$idowner.name"
    }}
])
```

Comment: but it turns out like this: "idowner" : [ { data } ] . is it possible to return only one "name" field?

Comment: I may be doing something wrong, but it doesn't work for me) Looks also: "idowner" : [ { data } ]

Comment: ok, I update further, please check now if it matches your result

Answer (score 0):

```
db.timelogs.aggregate([{ 
    $lookup: { 
                from: "user", 
                localField: "idowner.oid", 
                foreignField: "_id.oid", 
                as: "User" 
              } 
  }
  ,{$unwind:"$User"}
  ,{$project:{
   'User':'$User.name'
])
```

Comment: this is very close to the desired result, only how else then add all the data from the timelogs?